# Want to get exact domain name from address bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hosted my project in `www.example2.com`. I have a domain `www.example.com`. I created subdomain as `www.web.example.com` and redirected this to `www.example2.com`. Using URL masking this redirection done, in address bar www.web.example.com will appear, but actually files load from example2.com.  Now i need to fetch the subdomain name in my jquery. All these are based on my customer requirement. Any suggestions please.

I tried with

```
var currentHost = window.location.host;
```

it is printing example2.com, but I need only subdomain name "web.example.com"

Comment: If you're doing the redirection on the server side, the client will **never** be able to know that it originally came from `web.example.com`.

Comment: Yes , redirection done on domain side itself, any alternative way to find this, as because, client handles many sub domain, like web.example.com, web2.example.com etc, but mask domain is same example2.com.

Comment: You can either mask the URL, or you can let the client know what it is. You'll need to make your mind up what you want to achieve, and why. Also, it depends how exactly the masking is being done - there are different techniques